# Clicking link in Facebook Like posting on newsfeed results in 403 Forbidden error

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

1)  I installed a simple Facebook Like button on http://openhealthfees.com.  It works on this page but when I click the link in the posting on my Facebook newsfeed I'm sent to a 403 Forbidden page - as if I don't have permission to view my own site.

2) I've removed .htaccess from my root and all sites in my shared hosting account so I don't have a referrer problem.

3) My host can't find a problem on their end.

4) The url looks like this:

http://openhealthfees.com/?fb_action_ids=10201264806756917&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=other_multiline&action_object_map=%7B%2210201264806756917%22%3A1413864958830324%7D&action_type_map=%7B%2210201264806756917%22%3A%22og.likes%22%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D

5) I added a pile of Open Graph meta tags to the head.

6) I searched Google 3 days in a row and found nothing helpful. I found a few StackOverflow threads that came close.

I want just a simple social plugin, not an app, but in desperation I registered the site as a Facebook app and thrashed around with that for a while.

Any ideas what to try next?  I'm ready to promote this site to techies in Silicon Valley to get it started.  We'll need tens of thousands of likes to force the U.S. health insurance industry to provide us with JSON and XML fees of their prices so we can create marketplace platform apps.

Jim Preston
Santa Clara, CA

Comment: The URL you have shown works as soon as the tow parameters `action_object_map` and `action_type_map` are removed from it, resp. their values are replaced with something simpler like f.e. `1`. So there must be some kind of “filtering” going on on your server, for values that are considered potentially “harmful”. If it is nothing from your script/htaccess, then it must be something the hoster has implemented. They should have logs (or be able to generate them) that show what is filtered.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe but I removed those two params and same problem.  I suspect the host but they worked on this for two days and say it isn't on their server.  I'm not technical enough to know.  I still screw up CSS for IE :-)

Comment: http://openhealthfees.com/?fb_action_ids=10201264806756917&fb_action_types=og.likes&fb_source=other_multiline&action_ref_map=%5B%5D works for me and shows the page.

Comment: @CBroe Where did you click from? Your Facebook newsfeed?  Also, does clicking the link above show a 403 error or the site?  Really appreciate your time on this.  Jim

Comment: No, I’m saying these are likely to be the parameters that make your site react with a 403, cause if I take them out I can reach that URL. You will not be able to get Facebook to _not_ append these parameters, so you will have to look into it from your side, and see why your site rejects those parameters or values.

Comment: @CBroe  Thanks for working this.  The problem is the host support staff says they are having no problem liking and linking.  I can't drive 6 hours to L.A. to watch them click :-)  Since I have no .htaccess files on my site I can't think of a way to fix this.  Others are having this problem.

Comment: Well the problem occurs for me to when I just click the link you posted – so it must be something on the server. You should ask them for the log files (access & error log) – maybe there’s something in there why the request gets blocked. And ask them what kin of security-related modules/extensions they might have installed on the server. Those to parameters pass JSON data, maybe some kind of filter see that as a “hacking” attempt or something.

Comment: @CBroe  My host can't replicate the problem and their server log shows no errors.  The server log in my CPanel shows no errors.  However, if a create a 404 error by trying to access the /images folder then this shows in the log.  

I changed the message in my 403 page but that isn't what display now.

Could this 403 forbidden error be from Facebook's server? Instead of linking directly to my site it is somehow going through FB?  This is a weird problem :-(

Comment: I deleted the FB app and rebuilt it but the problem remains.

Comment: The comments and send button are working.  Links to the site will get users to the site. Clicking the link in the Like button popover has less params and passes the user to the site.

The top part of the link from the Like in a Facebook feed works.  Something in the bottom params are triggering the 403 error but FB generates these and the developer can't control them:


Something in this part causes a 403 error.  It is after the fb_source:

&action_object_map=%7B%2210201332743895303%22%3A246464588839729%7D&action_type_map=%7B%2210201332743895303%22%3A%22og.likes%22%7D&action_ref_map=%5B%5D

Comment: As of 26 October 2013 I wasn't able to solve this problem or find competent help on oDesk and Elance so I'm abandoning the Like button on my projects and coding my own solution with Facebook login.  Hopefully that will work.